# Как в параметр data запихнуть ещё одну переменную js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

У меня есть сериализация всех переменных формы, но мне плюсом к этому в параметр data нужно добавить еще одну переменную, которую я регистрирую уже в функции при отправке ajax

```
  function call(clicked_id) {


var clicked_idd = clicked_id;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'res.php',
      data: $('#formx').serialize(), //сюда нужно + передать еще переменную clicked_idd
      success: function(data) {
        $('#results').html(data);
        $
      },
      error:  function(xhr, str){
  alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
      }
    });

}
```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: `data : { 'form': $('#formx').serialize(), 'clicked_id': clicked_idd }`

Comment: Тогда он все данные смешивает в одной переменной form

Comment: Так и доставайте эти данные на сервере из переменной `form`, в чём проблема?

Comment: Как тогда их разбить снова на элемента массива в php потом

Comment: Так у вас в переменной `form` должны быть все данные из формы, в виде объекта. А в переменной `clicked_id` - ваш `clicked_idd`, у вас проблема с тем, чтобы доставать данные из переменной `form`? Добавьте в вопрос результат вызова `echo ($_POST)`

Comment: array(2) { ["form"]=> string(58) "get_id=0&months=&ton=5&price=&amount=&autoservices=&total=" ["clicked_id"]=> string(1) "5" } - это var_dump, т.к. echo выведит просто array

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте data = {...data, clicked_idd}.

Comment: Ничего не выходит

Comment: Как? success: function(data) {
       data = {...data, clicked_idd};
       $('#results').html(data);
      }, не выходит?

Comment: Попробуйте if (typeof data === 'object') data.clicked_idd = clicked_idd.

Comment: Может быть как-нибудь добавить в массив $('#formx').serialize() в конец ещё один элемент id со значением clicked_id,  только вот я не знаю как